# Spring .andExpect() MockMvc Logical || Equivalent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I'd like to write something like this:

```
mvc.perform(post(url))
    .andExpect(model().hasErrors() || model().attribute("errors", isNotNull()));
```

To test if either the model has BindingResult errors from an @Valid annotation in the controller method, or one of my own errors were added to the page. Is this possible?

I think something like hamcrest's `anyOf()` might be what I want, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: An alternative to what I'm doing is to add all errors to the binding result, which I didn't know you could do: `bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("Error", "Description."));` However, I'd still like to know how to do this OR in tests for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check if there are error while calling the url then you can just check the status of the returning response.

If you just want to check if the page throws an error then try below code:-

```
mvc.perform(post(url))
    .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError());
```

And also you can write your own custom error that throws `5xx` status code.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however, it is testing something slightly different: the correct HTTP code might be thrown without displaying the errors on the page.